# I have to calculate difference of sum of diagonal elements of a square matrix

Tags: c++

In the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int diagonalDifference(int x[][],int n)
{
    int sum1=0,sum2=0,y;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum1+=x[i][i];
        sum2+=x[i][n-1-i];
    }
    y=abs(sum1-sum2);
    return y;   
}
int main()
{
    int n,**z;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    z=diagonalDifference(arr,n);
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error I don't understand.

> ```
> error:declaration of 'x' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
> ```

Could you help me fix it?

Comment: You have *multiple* problem with your code. First of all C++ doesn't support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Secondly compare the type of `z` and the return-type of `diagonalDifference`.

Answer (score 2):

`int[][]` is not a valid type:

```
int diagonalDifference(int x[][],int n)
```

You declare `z` as an `int**`:

```
int n,**z;
```

But you assign it an `int`:

```
int diagonalDifference(int x[][],int n);
z=diagonalDifference(arr,n);
```

And finally you print `x` which does not exist:

```
cout<<x;
```

As rules of thumb:

- declare only one variable per line, and give it a meaningful name;
- declare what possibly can [as `const`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness);
- Don't use C-style arrays unless you *have to*; prefer [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for instance;
- [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5470596);
- [much more you need to learn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5470596).

.

```
int diagonalDifference(int x**,int n) { /* .... */ }

int matrix_size = 0;
std::cin >> matrix_size;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix{matrix_size, std::vector<int>{matrix_size}};
/* fill the matrix */

const int diag_diff = diagonalDifference(matrix, matrix_size);
std::cout << diag_diff << '\n';
```